# Static file collection in Django path error

Tags: python, django

My static file collector seems to suddenly be having problems, when attempting to load a page of my application I get the error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'/Users/Oscar/Google Drive/Development/REDACTED/REDACTED/static/less"
```

It seems a ' character has been appended to the path even though it is properly defined as

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../static/')
```

In the settings.

The error seems to be occuring in the django-pipeline package somewhere and I'm completely stumped. Any ideas?

EDIT: just some more info

The error is triggered at template rendering, specifically this line:

```
{% compressed_css 'styles' %}
```

Comment: http://marklmiddleton.com/2013/using-less-with-django-on-heroku/ read about local dev

Comment: That describes a separate toolchain to what I'm using. Also everything I have was working fine last time I used it. All that's changed is the code path and for some reason this ' character is now being appended which wasn't happening before.

Comment: Is a ```git diff``` out of the question, I suppose? You could use ```grep -ri '<characters>' <path/to/search/recursevly>``` for this ```'``` if you suspect any characters that might precede or follow it, or you could just disable django-pipeline, verify that everything works and enable it step by step.

Comment: Okay so I restored the same code but in my Dropbox folder, the only thing that has changed therefore is the path has 'Dropbox' in it rather than 'Google Drive'. Everything then works fine, could the white space in the path be causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in the version of django-pipeline I am using where paths with spaces result in issues in locating the folder. I achieved a temporary fix by changing the app directory so it is in a path where there are no spaces in the path name.